# Getting the wrong Count result in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

I have written an `SQL` query to try and get some information on a group of trees by forest type. However, when I run this query, the `Count(T_Plots.ID_plot) AS [Plots/Forest Type]`, returns the same numbers as the `Count(T_Trees.ID_Tree) AS [Trees/Forest Type]`. These numbers are way too high, since the entire `T_Plots` table only has 175 records, while in the results table it returns outcomes as high as 4290.

What did I overlook that is causing these wrong numbers, and how do I get the correct number of plots per forest type?

```
SELECT
T_Plots.Forest_type,
Count(T_Plots.ID_plot) AS [Plots/Forest Type],
Count(T_Trees.ID_Tree) AS [Trees/Forest Type],
[Trees/Forest Type]/[Plots/Forest Type]*10 AS [Trees/Ha],
Avg([T_Trees.DBH (cm)])/100*Avg([T_Trees.Height (m)])*0.7*[Trees/Ha] AS [Volume (m3)/Ha],
3.142*(((Avg([T_Trees.DBH (cm)])/2)^2)/100)*[Trees/Ha] AS [BA (m2)/Ha]

FROM T_Plots INNER JOIN T_Trees
ON T_Plots.ID_plot = T_Trees.ID_plot

GROUP BY T_Plots.Forest_type
```

Images:[T_Plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WowwY.png) [T_Trees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t32fw.png) [Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtZLH.png)

Comment: `COUNT(<expression>)` counts the number of non-`NULL` values of the expression.  It is not surprising that your two counts are returning the same value.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think a `DISTINCT` might solve your problem. Try:

```
SELECT
T_Plots.Forest_type,
Count(Distinct T_Plots.ID_plot) AS [Plots/Forest Type],
Count(Distinct T_Trees.ID_Tree) AS [Trees/Forest Type],
[Trees/Forest Type]/[Plots/Forest Type]*10 AS [Trees/Ha],
Avg([T_Trees.DBH (cm)])/100*Avg([T_Trees.Height (m)])*0.7*[Trees/Ha] AS [Volume (m3)/Ha],
3.142*(((Avg([T_Trees.DBH (cm)])/2)^2)/100)*[Trees/Ha] AS [BA (m2)/Ha]

FROM T_Plots INNER JOIN T_Trees
ON T_Plots.ID_plot = T_Trees.ID_plot

GROUP BY T_Plots.Forest_type
```